# Is there a way to avoid the loss of EXIF data when resizing images on upload?

Tags: media

In Drupal 7, when editing a core image field, under **Maximum image resolution**, it states:

> Resizing images on upload will cause the loss of EXIF data in the
>   image.

Is there a way (module) to resize images on upload without losing EXIF data, or is it in the nature of server-side resizing that this data will be lost?  I'm trying to keep the orientation of my pictures correct (resized pictures often appear at silly angles) but I also want to keep file sizes down at the same time.

Comment: Might it be the same issue as [this one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54774/iphone-uploded-images-rotated)?

Comment: @Clive Yes, I missed that answer.  Imagecache Actions and the Autorotate submodule can solve this issue.

Comment: I would say that this is an error in Drupal core, in the image file upload handling. IMO, removing exif data on resize is correct, but removing and ignoring the rotation is not.